# What size capacitor and or components do I need to run 12V starter motor with solar panels as power and relays for switches

Tags: solar-cell, 12v

I'm trying to use solar panels to operate a DC 12-volt small starter motor at slow speed to rotate my solar panels towards the Sun automatically.

The size of solar panels that it take to power the 12 volt motor is just as big as the panels that I have that they're going to be rotating.  I need to know what size capacitor I could use to supply enough power to control the motor. Would it be better to use a capacitor with the solar panel to operate a relay to power the motor from a battery source?

Comment: That looks like a 101 word sentence. Make it easy on the reader and break it down. What current does the motor take when driving the panels?

Comment: Hello and welcome.  You'll get the best answers if you put a lot more detail in your question.  May I suggest avoiding words like "small", as that very much depends on an individual's expectations, and is very likely to be misunderstood: numbers are much more helpful.  Could you post a photo of your motors, perhaps, and the mechanical arrangement or gearing?  Or measure how much current they take?  How many panels (per motor)?  How big are the panels?  You can imagine that a 10 W panel with a model motor is a different situation from lots of 20 kg 400W panels.

Comment: Consider also adding diagrams, pictures, and links to what you're using. Explain what you've figured out so far.

Comment: you might have designed the motor too big. If you use enough gears, you only need a very small motor because the sun moves very slowly.

Comment: A starter motor seems like very much the wrong choice. They are around a couple horsepower for a smallish one (for a 4-cylinder ICE). As user253751 points out, the sun doesn't tend to move across the sky very quickly on this planet, so maybe a couple of orders of magnitude less power and some gearing would make more sense. More like the tiny motors used to move side mirrors on a car.